# Check Neighbors Attribute

Tags: netlogo

How can I reference the neighbor turtle in the following statement?

```
if count(turtles-on patch-ahead -1) with [(target-speed) > (target-speed)] > 0
```

I would like to compare the speed of the neighbor turtle to that of self.

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086966/comparing-two-agent-variables) or [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770317/netlogo-comparing-turtle-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `count agentset > 0`, try if `any? agentset`

You want to use `[target-speed] of myself`

So, to put it together.

```
if any? turtles-on patch-ahead -1 with [target-speed > [target-speed] of myself]
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for